# Convert field from integer to string in one rails Active Record relation before sending json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, type-conversion

In my Rails 4 app, I actually send an active record relation in JSON with:

```
[...]
wine['varietals'] = record.varietals
@wines << wine

format.json { render :json => { :success => "OK", :items => @wines } }
[...]
```

*wine['varietals']* is an array of AR relations. My problem is the varietal model contains a field named grape_id that is an integer. I need to send it in string for my WS. I don't want to make a custom conversion to JSON just for this field.

How to force this field to be string before the automatic JSON conversion ? If possible I don't want to make an array of hashes and keep the AR style with dot: *model.field*

```
wine['varietals'].each do |varietal| 
   varietal.grape_id.to_s 
end
```

Of course this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Rails models have an `as_json` method that gets called when rednering the model to JSON.  You can override this method within your models to set up custom JSON formatting.  In your case, you may want to add something like this to your `Wine` model:

```
def as_json(opts = {})
  json = super(opts)
  json["grape_id"] = self.grape_id.to_s
  json
end
```

The method gives you the default model JSON when you call the `super` method and set it to the `json` variable, then stringifies `grape_id` and sets it in the JSON, and finally returns the updated JSON.

Now, any time a controller returns a JSON version of single Wine model, or an association of multiple Wine models, the JSON will be formatted through this updated method and the `grape_id` will be stringified every time.

Comment: It works like a charm! And great MVC used there to avoid changing something in the controller. Thanks MoskeyOmbus.